# Is there a function/trick to compare elements of an array without a loop?

Tags: arrays, vba, performance

I am looking for an efficient way for doing element-wise comparisons on an array. For example, I want to check if each element of `test_array` is `>=2` and return an array of corresponding booleans.

So, **input**: `test_array = Array(1,2,3)`, **arguments**: `>=2`, desired **output**: `(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE)`.

Is there a way to do this for the whole array, without a loop
<strike>(which is inefficient for large arrays)</strike>? Maybe a trick similar to summing up two arrays without a loop by using the `MMULT` function..? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: A simple for-loop with only an if-else statement (no other functions/operations) is very efficient, so the above trick is not needed (for this purpose) anymore. Thanks to @BigBen for pointing it out.

Comment: A loop is not inefficient for large arrays. Just tested on an array with 10 million elements. Creating the original array and the boolean array took under a second.

Comment: what about using map function on linq?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Ro There is no Linq in VBA.  You can create a Map function using a Wrapper object for a scripting dictionary but this is just hiding the loop.

Comment: @BigBen thank you for pointing this out. Indeed A simple for-loop with an If-Else statement is very quick. The inefficiency was due to the fact that I was using an excel function (from Application.WorksheetFunction, Min in this case) to populate the new array.

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr= [1,2,3,4]
let newOne = arr.map(e=>e>=2?true:false)
console.log(newOne) //prints [false, true, true, true]
```

Here I used map function instead of using loop